# how to convert all pandas duplicates to a dictionary?

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, duplicates

I have a dataframe where it has a column with categories and another column with words. Words can be repeated in the different categories, and therefore there can be duplicates. However, I would like to put these duplicates together in a dictionary, as follows:

### Dataframe

```py
category  | word       | score

happy     | tolerance  | 0.91
unhappy   | tolerance  | 0.12
angry     | kill       | 1.0
confident | tolerance  | 0.56
friendly  | tolerance  | 0.70
happy     | kill       | 0.01

...
```

### Expected dictionary:

```py
d = {
    'tolerance' = {'happy': 0.91, 'angry': 0.01, 'confident': 0.56, 'friendly': 0.70},
     'kill' = {'happy': 0.01, 'angry': 1.0, 'confident': 0.32, 'friendly': 0.016},
     ... 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could construct the resulting `dict` directly, like so:

```
new_d = {}
for g, d in df.groupby('word'):
    new_d[g] = d.set_index('category')['score'].to_dict()
```

The `pd.DataFrame.to_dict` method, when passing `orient='index'` does not support multiple index keys (if you set `word` as index, for example).